# Naive-Bayes Iris R, Correct Implementation?

Tags: r, self-study, classification, naive-bayes

So I am trying to understand the naive Bayes classifier by implementing it in R. However I'm not sure if my implementation is correct.

Using the iris dataset and Sepal Width / Length as features. First we count the number of observations in each class:

```
library(dplyr)

ir <- iris

Species        `n()`
<fct>         <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

So there are three distinct classes with each occurring 50 times. Next we calculate the mean and variance of each feature for each class:

```
 suf_stats <- ir %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(
                mu_sep_len = mean(Sepal.Length), 
                var_sep_len = var(Sepal.Length), 
                mu_sep_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
                var_sep_width = var(Sepal.Width))

  Species        mu_sep_len var_sep_len mu_sep_width var_sep_width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 setosa           5.01       0.124         3.43        0.144 
  2 versicolor       5.94       0.266         2.77        0.0985
  3 virginica        6.59       0.404         2.97        0.104
```

Next we calculate the probability of each observation for each class:

```
pbs <- cbind(
          dnorm(ir[, 1], unlist(suf_stats[1,2]), unlist(suf_stats[1,3])) * 
          dnorm(ir[, 2], unlist(suf_stats[1,4]), unlist(suf_stats[1,5])),
          dnorm(ir[, 1], unlist(suf_stats[2,2]), unlist(suf_stats[2,3])) * 
          dnorm(ir[, 2], unlist(suf_stats[2,4]), unlist(suf_stats[2,5])), 
          dnorm(ir[, 1], unlist(suf_stats[3,2]), unlist(suf_stats[3,3])) * 
          dnorm(ir[, 2], unlist(suf_stats[3,4]), unlist(suf_stats[3,5]))
)
```

and select the one with the highest probability:

```
apply(pbs, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[38] 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2
[75] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3
[112] 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3
[149] 3 3
```

which results in the following plot:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, ir$Sepal.Width, col = ir$Species, pch = 19)
points(iris$Sepal.Length, ir$Sepal.Width, col = apply(pbs, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x))), pch = 3, cex = 2)
```

[image]

where the points are the original data, and the cross hairs are the classified values. We can see that there are some miss classifications, but that's life.

Note: since the prior probabilities are all the same, i left multiplication, since it should not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the rigt track. You missed a few things. First, within the `dnorm` function you are supposed to use the standard deviation and not the variance. Therefore instead of computing variance, you should rather compute the standard deviation.

2nd You are supposed to normalize the probabilities in that they add up to 1. Of course this is not necessary but it is sufficient for comparison.

Also if possible, for numerical stability and high accuracy, you should consider using the log ie `dnorm(...., log = TRUE) + dnorm(..., log = TRUE)` then latter on exponentiate.

In your case, you could do:

```
suf_stats <- ir %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(
                mu_sep_len = mean(Sepal.Length), 
                sd_sep_len = sd(Sepal.Length), # Change to sd
                mu_sep_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
                sd_sep_width = sd(Sepal.Width)) # Change to sd
```

then do `pbs <- prop.table(pbs, 1)`

Now compare your results to the results obtained by the `naiveBayes` function in R:

```
pbs1 <- e1071:::predict.naiveBayes(e1071::naiveBayes(iris[1:2], iris[, 5]), iris, 'raw')

all.equal(pbs, pbs1, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

To get the specific classes, just do:

```
max.col(pbs)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[40] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
[79] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3
[118] 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2
```

For the confusion matrix/misclassification do:

```
table(ir$Species, max.col(pbs))
            
              1  2  3
  setosa     49  1  0
  versicolor  0 37 13
  virginica   0 19 31
```